# nodejs TypeError: Object prototype may only be an Object or null

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, static, hosting

При попытке запустить проект в production режиме на хостинге, происходит ошибка. В чем может быть проблема? На локальном сервере в development режиме все нормально запускается.

Ошибка:

```
root@cyber-insurance-diploma-project:~/cyber-insurance-diploma-project# npm run start

> cyber-insurance-diploma-project@1.0.0 start /root/cyber-insurance-diploma-project
> cross-env NODE_ENV=production node app.js

/root/cyber-insurance-diploma-project/node_modules/serve-static/index.js:48
  var opts = Object.create(options || null)
                    ^

TypeError: Object prototype may only be an Object or null: client
    at Function.create (<anonymous>)
    at Function.serveStatic [as static] (/root/cyber-insurance-diploma-project/node_modules/serve-static/index.js:48:21)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/root/cyber-insurance-diploma-project/app.js:18:24)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:999:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1027:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:863:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:708:14)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:60:12)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! cyber-insurance-diploma-project@1.0.0 start: `cross-env NODE_ENV=production node app.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the cyber-insurance-diploma-project@1.0.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2021-12-15T16_57_28_906Z-debug.log
root@cyber-insurance-diploma-project:~/cyber-insurance-diploma-project#
```

scripts from package.json:

```
  "scripts": {
    "start": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production node app.js",
    "server": "nodemon app.js",
    "client": "npm run start --prefix client",
    "client:install": "npm install --prefix client",
    "client:build": "npm run build --prefix client",
    "dev": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development concurrently \"npm run server\" \"npm run client\""
  },
```

Фрагмент app.js:

```
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
  app.use('/', express.static(path.join(__dirname), 'client', 'build'));

  app.get('*', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, 'client', 'build', 'index.html'));
  });
}
```

Comment: `at Object.<anonymous> (/root/cyber-insurance-diploma-project/app.js:18:24)`
18-я строка, это где express.static

Comment: `path.join(__dirname), 'client', 'build'` <- скобка path.join закрыта не там где должна

Comment: @nörbörnën, просто нет слов, спасибо огромное, все запустилось)